# disable/renable input field base on radio checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote below code but there's no respond I switch my radio box. I want to disable unchecked radio checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/prxteafy/1/

```
<input class="radio-checkbox" type="radio" name="choice" value="custom_msg" checked>Custom Message :<br/>
<input style="width:200px" placeholder="your msg" type="text" id="custom_text"/>

<br/>

<input class="radio-checkbox" type="radio" name="choice" value="custom_img">Image :<br/>
<input style="width:200px" placeholder="an image url" type="text" id="custom_img"/>
```

my js

```
$(".radio-checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).next().$("input").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: Your problem here was the part `next().$("input")`, which was not working (not a function error was logged). Instead I used `next().next()` and it worked. Your `<br />`s were immediate siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using correct [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/). I think you can sum it up to this using [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/):

```js
$(".radio-checkbox").click(function() {
  $("input:text").prop("disabled", true);
  $(this).nextAll("input").eq(0).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="radio-checkbox" type="radio" name="choice" value="custom_msg" checked>Custom Message :
<br/>
<input style="width:200px" placeholder="your msg" type="text" id="custom_text" />
<br/>
<input class="radio-checkbox" type="radio" name="choice" value="custom_img">Image :
<br/>
<input style="width:200px" placeholder="an image url" type="text" id="custom_img" disabled />
```

Comment: Why not just `.next('input')` rather than `.nextAll('input').eq(0)`?

Comment: Because `next()` isn't input but a `<br />` :) For example `$(this).next().next()` could work.

Comment: That's what I get for not reading all of the HTML! Not obvious in the original code because it's just on the end of the line, though I notice you've moved them onto separate lines in your answer. That said, looks like there's a connection between the `value` on the radio buttons and the `id` on the text boxes, so could use an ID selector rather than relying on DOM traversal. Would be more resistant to layout changes.

Comment: Kinda nice idea indeed but not both `text`/`radio` has the same id/value :S Would be nice though

Comment: I'm just going to give up, I clearly can't read properly today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Your question and jsfiddle confused me, do you want to disable input box when select radio button or do you want reverse of it.

Below is code to disable input box for checked radio button

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".radio-checkbox").click(function() {
     $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").removeProp("disabled");          
     $(this).next().next("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prxteafy/17/)**

And this code will do the reverse, this will enable input for checked radio button

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $(".radio-checkbox").click(function() {
         $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true);          
         $(this).next().next("input[type=text]").removeProp('disabled');
      });

    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prxteafy/19/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `js` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".radio-checkbox").change(function() {
       if (this.value == 'custom_msg') {
            $("#custom_img").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#custom_text").prop('disabled', false);
       }
       else if (this.value == 'custom_img') {
            $("#custom_text").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#custom_img").prop('disabled', false);
       }
    });

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kupendra/prxteafy/20/)